# Does a 5v 3A / 2A power adapter work where a requirement is of 5v 4a/5A

Tags: power-supply

Does a 5v 3A / 2A power adapter work where a requirement is of 5v 4a/5A
Kind of confused, please help

Comment: What have to be powered by this power supply?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a chance that the device you are powering with this adapter will try and draw more current than what it can supply thereby overheating (and eventually burning out) the adapter. The highest possible current that the charger can supply is 3A and the lowest current draw of the device being powered is 4A. Best not to use it.